# pyspark PandasUDFDType.SCALAR convert Row array has wrong

Tags: series, pyspark

I want to use PandasUDFDType.SCALAR to operate the Row arrays like belows:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([([1, 2, 3, 2],), ([4, 5, 5, 4],)], ['data'])

@pandas_udf(ArrayType(IntegerType()), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def s(x):
    z = x.apply(lambda xx: xx*2)
    return z
df.select(s(df.data)).show()
```

but it went wrong:

````
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: trying to convert NumPy type int32 but got int64```
````

Comment: The same code works for me

Comment: which version of your pandas, spark, pyarrow and numpy?

Comment: `('0.25.2', '2.4.4', '0.13.0', '1.16.3')` in the same order

Comment: This may be the pyarrow's reason, I have replaced the pyarrow 0.8.0 with pyarrow 0.13.0, it worked!